# Using NSUrl in my ios app send data encrypted to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have an api that is stored at:

https://my-api-site.com

If I access it using the following code my passing in my login password to the server via the post, is my data encrpted from my iphone app to the server/api?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my-api-site.com"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url       standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//initialize a post data

NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"username", @"username",
                          @"password", @"password", nil];

NSError *error=nil;

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted     error:&error];



[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//start the connection
[connection start];
```

Does the app to server send encrypted data?

Answer (score 0):

**Since you are using https connection.**
Yes, it is SSL/TLS encrypted. You are protected from an MitM attacks.

> In its popular deployment on the internet, HTTPS provides
>   authentication of the website and associated web server with which one
>   is communicating, which protects against man-in-the-middle attacks.
>   Additionally, it provides bidirectional encryption of communications
>   between a client and server, which protects against eavesdropping and
>   tampering with or forging the contents of the communication.

MORE INFO

[HTTPS connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

Https connections are secure but you can also use Base64 Encryption or AES Encryption to send data over network, if your data is too crucial. You have to encrypt the values first and then send those values as dictionary in body.